# usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 315: wait_for: No record of process 30388

Tags: linux, bash, shell, suse

Openating system:**SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3**

Bash version:**4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)**

bash rpm version：**bash-4.3-82.1.x86_64**

```
node1:/var/log # rpm -q bash
bash-4.3-82.1.x86_64

node2:/var/log # bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
node2:/var/log # lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE
Description:    SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3
Release:        12.3
Codename:       n/a
```

I have a service named ce1800v. it's main process is ce1800vd.sh.

**Every second** it checks it's subprocess's status with command `cat /proc/${process_id}/stat`

if return value of this command is not zero or process status is `Z` (means zombie state), i will restart the service.

Below is the part of the code：

```sh
process_info=$(cat /proc/${process_id}/stat 2>/dev/null)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    error_info="Get process ${process_id} info failed."
 else
```

Howerver, inexplicably, the check command failed with output (`/var/log/messages`)

> usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 315: wait_for: No record of process 30388

I searched a lot and found that `bash 4.3.42` has a bug with same phenomenon. However different triggering causes.

**I do not set `lastpipe` option.**

- [lastpipe' leads to "wait_for: No record of process" errors](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1809765)
- [Why does my bash script show messages like “foo.sh: line 55: wait_for: No record of process 60227”?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4888481)
- [shopt -s lastpipe & "no record of process" warnings](https://bug-bash.gnu.narkive.com/tsyjXc9E/4-3-42-shopt-s-lastpipe-no-record-of-process-warnings#post1)

This prolem happens almost everyday, but there's no pattern.

```
node2:/var/log # zgrep "wait_for" messages-202103*
messages-20210309.xz:2021-03-08T23:44:49.798309+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 35598
messages-20210310.xz:2021-03-09T11:51:31.799274+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 10211
messages-20210310.xz:2021-03-09T20:20:29.798511+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 1280: wait_for: No record of process 50678
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T02:29:22.119447+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 9656
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T11:14:25.802595+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 18307
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T12:43:49.806703+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 525: wait_for: No record of process 20453
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T13:06:15.804019+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 39166
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T17:11:51.672758+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 25945
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T19:07:41.514515+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 1280: wait_for: No record of process 55102
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T21:22:01.810217+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 31511
messages-20210311.xz:2021-03-10T23:41:52.429946+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 526: wait_for: No record of process 42884
messages-20210312.xz:2021-03-11T00:26:53.845105+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 18142
messages-20210312.xz:2021-03-11T05:23:53.346956+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 31932
messages-20210312.xz:2021-03-11T08:01:19.918593+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 1280: wait_for: No record of process 39101
messages-20210312.xz:2021-03-11T09:02:23.804787+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 46670
messages-20210312.xz:2021-03-11T10:57:43.229498+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 526: wait_for: No record of process 2109
messages-20210312.xz:2021-03-11T12:10:57.874531+08:00 node2 ce1800vd.sh[3290]: /usr/ce1800v/bin/ce1800vd.sh: line 462: wait_for: No record of process 35847
```

I tried to upgrade my Centos bash from `4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`. to `4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`. But can not reproduce the problem. So i think Maybe have other cause.

I'm confused now and don't know how to proceed with this analysis next.

I want to know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Openating system:SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3
>
> Bash version:4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)

It seems that you're using a quite old bash RPM package.
Please check the installed RPM via

```
rpm -q bash
```

The initial SLES 12 SP3 version was 4.3-82.1.

The latest version from the Updates channel is 4.3-83.23.1.
This version resolves to

> GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release

Please first ensure that you have a valid subscription and an upgrade repository attached and then run

> zypper -v up bash

BTW, if even your bash package is outdated, your system is probably missing a lot more updates, so running

> zypper -v up

would be recommended.

Finally, since SLES 12 SP3 is out of support, please consider to migrate to a newer release, like SLES 12 SP5 or SLES 15 SP2.